# ORACLE SQL Coalesce date with static number

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am having an issue utilizing a coalesce function within Oracle.  I am in the midst of switching databases to Oracle and i am having an issue.

this is what i would like to run:
code from original query (ibm)

```
,COALESCE(period_dt, CAST('01-01-1900' AS DATE)) AS PERIOD_DT
```

where for this column, it returns the period_dt in the column, but if there is nothing, null, 0, etc, the returned value is the following in a date format: 01/01/1900

I have tried the following options:

```
COALESCE(TO_DATE(period_dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('01/01/1900', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) period_dt

,case when period_dt = 0 then to_date('01-01-1900', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  when period_dt = '' then to_date('01-01-1900', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  when period_dt = NULL then to_date('01-01-1900', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  else to_date(period_dt,'mm/dd/yyyy')
  END period_dt
```

Using certain combinations i have gotten errors that range from 'not a valid month' to 'inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER' and as i am unable to run this in the select statement, i am not entirely sure how i would put this in the groupby statement.  any help you can provide would be great.

Comment: Can you give some sample data for the `period_dt` column and what is its data type (date, number, varchar2)? Also, `WHEN period_dt = NULL` is never true; you want to use `WHEN period_dt IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ANSI date literals in Oracle:

```
, COALESCE(period_dt, DATE '1900-01-01') AS PERIOD_DT
```

`period_dt` is a date already. If it's filled you show it, if it's null you show January 1, 1900 instead.

Comment: @Thorsetn Kettner, thank you so much!  banging my head into desk for last several hours!